# What is the suspended state in network

Tags: android, networking

I am working on a xmpp project for Android device. Where I am to manage the xmpp connection. The connection is created and reconnected on connection lost. I saw some code where they managed the "suspended" state provided by ConnectivityReceiver class. So could anybody tell me when that suspended state comes.?

Answer (score 9):

The connected state indicates that your phone is connected and should be able to access IP traffic.
The suspended state indicates that your IP traffic is temporarily unavailable but you are still connected.

An example from the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#DATA_SUSPENDED) is when you have access to a `2G network` and you receive a phone call, the data traffic may be `suspended`.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.DetailedState.html) is the android documentation about the `suspended` state inside `NetworkInfo` who, i guess, happens in a similar case as the previous `TelephonyManager` example (data traffic required by other top level service).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer already given: the mobile network is set to suspended while approving a captive Wi-Fi network.

Another interesting thing is that networks are set to blocked after one minute when the option '*Block connections without VPN*' is enabled (Android Oreo and later).

Comment: can you give any documentation on these claims, I'm really interested and it's the first time I heard about blocked network after one minute etc.

Comment: The Android documentation is not that thorough I am afraid, so I know this from experience with my app NetGuard only.